# Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5) in for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a change macro but I get an error in a for loop, from my little knowledge I think everything is good and defined, but I keep getting the error, I tried some things but I had no luck, must be nothing fs, but I don't know what could be,

it fails in this part (also in the next for loop that's exactly the same)

```
            For i = 18 To 26
                Newvalueb = .Cells(i, tarcol).Formula
                If Len(Newvalueb) = "12" Then
                Else
                    Newvalue = Mid(Newvalueb, 12, Len(Newvalueb) - 18)
                    .Cells(i, tarcol).Value = "=SUM(" & .Cells(i, "E").Address & "," & Newvalue & ")"
               End If
            Next i
```

I normaly get the error trying to define `Newvalue` but sometimes when that doesn't fail it fails the next line

`.Cells(i, tarcol).Value = "=SUM(" & .Cells(i, "E").Address & "," & Newvalue & ")"` 
anyway, here's all my code, could be something else in a different part.

The for loop normaly works, cause I have it assigned in another `CommandButton`, so not working here is strange

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i, lastcol, tarcol As Long
Dim Newvalueb As String
Dim Newvalue As Variant

'On Error GoTo Exitsub

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=""

With ActiveSheet

    Application.EnableEvents = True
   
    

    For i = 73 To 62 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "B").Value) = True Then
        Else
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "G").Value) = True Then
                GoTo Hide
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    .Range("G12:L12").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End With
GoTo Cont

Hide:
ActiveSheet.Range("G12:L12").EntireRow.Hidden = True
GoTo Cont

Cont:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Range("J12").Value = "APPROVED" Then
            
    lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells(17, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    tarcol = lastcol - 3
            
        With ActiveSheet
    
            '.Shapes("CommandButton3").Delete
            '.Shapes("CommandButton2").Delete
            '.Shapes("CommandButton1").Delete

            '.Cells.Locked = False
            '.Cells.Locked = True

            For i = 18 To 26
                Newvalueb = .Cells(i, tarcol).Formula
                If Len(Newvalueb) = "12" Then
                Else
                    Newvalue = Mid(Newvalueb, 12, Len(Newvalueb) - 18)
                    .Cells(i, tarcol).Value = "=SUM(" & .Cells(i, "E").Address & "," & Newvalue & ")"
                End If
            Next i
            
            
            For i = 35 To 53
                Newvalueb = .Cells(i, tarcol).Formula
                If Len(Newvalueb) = "12" Then
                Else
                    Newvalue = Mid(Newvalueb, 12, Len(Newvalueb) - 18)
                    .Cells(i, tarcol).Value = "=SUM(" & .Cells(i, "E").Address & "," & Newvalue & ")"
                End If
            Next i
    
            If .Cells(17, tarcol - 2).Value > 1 Then
                .Range(.Cells(16, tarcol - 2), .Cells(27, tarcol - 1)).Delete xlShiftToLeft
                .Range(.Cells(33, tarcol - 2), .Cells(54, tarcol - 1)).Delete xlShiftToLeft
            Else
            End If

        End With
    Else
    End If
    
Exitsub:

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="", _
UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
Contents:=True, _
AllowFormattingCells:=False, _
AllowFormattingColumns:=False, _
AllowFormattingRows:=False, _
AllowInsertingColumns:=False, _
AllowInsertingRows:=False, _
AllowDeletingColumns:=False, _
AllowDeletingRows:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Likely `Len(Newvalueb) - 18` is negative.

Comment: Btw, `Len` certainly doesn't return a `String` so get rid of the quotes around `12` in `If Len(Newvalueb) = "12" Then`.

Comment: @BigBen Now it fails the next line :c

Comment: What's the value of `Newvalue` when it fails? i.e. what does `Debug.Print Newvalue` return to the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen just a "$"

Comment: ... which creates an invalid formula.

Answer (score 0):

Since cell's address should be 2 letters at least (but it can be 1-letter name, of cause)

```
For i = 18 To 26
    Newvalueb = .Cells(i, tarcol).Formula
    If Len(Newvalueb) = 12 Then
    ' something missing here?
    Else
        If Len(Newvalueb) > 19 Then
            Newvalue = Mid(Newvalueb, 12, Len(Newvalueb) - 18)
            .Cells(i, tarcol).Value = "=SUM(" & .Cells(i, "E").Address & "," & Newvalue & ")"
        end if
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Did the solution help?